# how to access the initialized data in windbg through offset from IDA

Tags: ida, windbg

In IDA, I see a value called dword_1C0203AB4 which doesn't have a symbol name. I want to view the value in system. My windbg is connected to the system and the driver files in system and IDA is the same. My approach is to calculate the offset and add it to the base memory.

```
start
.text:00000001C0001000 _text           segment para public 'CODE' use64
.text:00000001C0001000                 assume cs:_text
.text:00000001C0001000                 ;org 1C0001000h
.text:00000001C0001000                 assume es:nothing, ss:nothing, ds:_data, fs:nothing, gs:nothing
.text:00000001C0001000                 db 8 dup(0CCh)
.text:00000001C0001008
.text:00000001C0001008 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:00000001C0001008
.text:00000001C0001008
.text:00000001C0001008 ; __int64 __fastcall TcpNotifyBacklogChangeSend(PKSPIN_LOCK SpinLock)
.text:00000001C0001008 TcpNotifyBacklogChangeSend proc near    ; CODE XREF: TcpNotifyTcbDelay+337↓p
.text:00000001C0001008                                         ; DATA XREF: .pdata:ExceptionDir↓o
...
...
.data:00000001C0203AB4 dword_1C0203AB4 dd 0FFFFh               ; DATA XREF: CTcpQueryTimeStamp+6↑r
.data:00000001C0203AB4                                         ; CTcpQueryTimeStamp+51↑w ...
.data:00000001C0203AB8 icmpPingLowWaterMark dd 1F4h            ; DATA XREF: IppInspectLocalDatagramsIn+5FED5↑r
.data:00000001C0203ABC EQoSpPolicyAppMarkingSetting dd 0FFFFFFFEh
.data:00000001C0203ABC                                         ; DATA XREF: EQoSUpdateAppMarkingSetting+A↑r
.data:00000001C0203ABC                                         ; EQoSProcessGlobalSettings+35↓r ...
.data:00000001C0203AC0 EQoSpPolicyTcpAutoTuningSetting dd 0FFFFFFFFh
```

So the offset should be 202AB4

```
kd> lm m tcpip

start     end      module name
fffff803'6b750000 fffff803'6ba6a000  tcpip (pdb symbols)
```

However, the value is not what I want(0xFFFF) and the initial address function in IDA and windbg is not the same

```
kd> u fffff8036b750000
tcpip! WFPDatagramDataShimV4 <PERF> (tcpip+0x0):
fffff803`6b750000 4d5a      pop   r10
```

What's the correct approach to calculate the address value dword_1C0203AB4?

Comment: How 2ab4 ? .text is not start of module

Comment: 4d5a is MZ the pe file signature  why are you disassembling pe header

Comment: Use rebase in ida to synchronise windbg with ida this has to be done per session if ASLR is active

Comment: In your example, you're forgetting to add the offset that you calculated (0x202AB4). I.e., you're saying one thing and doing another. Once you have the offset, though, you can add it to the module name in windbag: `? tcpip.sys+$offset`

Comment: @AliRizvi-Santiago. No he serms to be subtracting the start of .text which is typically 0x1000 greater than image  so his value is 0x1000 less   it should be xxx3ab4    and in windbg he seems to disassembling. At image base and saying it doesnt match the function which  is 0x1000 bytes ahead in start of .text section

Comment: @blabb, Ah, I see my misunderstanding. Thx for pointing it out. Itś strange to calculate the offset and not attempt to use in the example that follows. But yea, you're right. He's miscalculating the offset entirely... didn't you include this as an answer already? Perhaps I'm misremembering...

Comment: IDAPython (7.x):
`idaapi.inf_get_min_ea() - idc.get_screen_ea()`

IDAPython (6.x):
`idaapi.get_inf_structure().minEA - idc.ScreenEA()`

Comment: i thought i would wait for feedback but the op seems to have jumped to another question and left this dangling so just posted the comment contents as answer

Comment: @blabb have a lot of work to do. Will post my trial later:-)

Comment: @AliRizvi-Santiago This expression is wrong in my case. ida_ida.inf_get_min_ea() is 0x1c0001000. It's not the real image base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the offset should be 202AB4

no

```
.data:00000001C0203AB4 dword_1C0203AB4 dd 0FFFFh
```

subtract ImageBase from this not start of .text
to get imagebase you scroll to the top and read the summary
use idapython get_imagebase
or go to edit->rebase and copy the imagebase that shows up there by default

in your case it would be 203AB4

and in windbg you are disassembling at moduleBase or ImageBase instead of
Disassembling at start of .text
so the functions do not match

```
0: kd> u tcpip+0x1008 l1
tcpip!TcpNotifyBacklogChangeSend:
fffff800`883f1008 4053            push    rbx
0: kd>
```

btw the offset 3ab4 also appears to be wrong
it seems to be at 3a74 (may be different versions of tcpip.sys )

```
data:00000001C0203A74 dword_1C0203A74 dd 0FFFFh               ; DATA XREF: CTcpQueryTimeStamp+6↑r
.data:00000001C0203A74                                         ; CTcpQueryTimeStamp+51↑w ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just followed the guide from blabb. In my IDA, it's Edit->Segments->Rebase program. The image base is 0x1C0000000 instead of 1C0001000. The PE has some other headers before the section headers(.text,.data etc) to provide other essential information for the OS to manage files.

The command Ali gave me was not working due to [spec](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/ida74_idapython_no_bc695_porting_guide.shtml). The below command should work but it didn't subtract the real image base and the output was the same as the wrong one.

```
ida_ida.inf_get_min_ea()-idc.get_screen_ea()
```

Comment: yea, blabb's answer is right. especially as i misunderstood the question to begin with, saw his correct answer posted, and then removed before you even got a chance to see it until it was updated a month later. `inf_get_min_ea `returns the lowest loaded address in the database, so it depends on how it's loaded, whereas `get_imagebase` returns it correctly all the time.

i highly recommend using the ida-minsc plugin, as the function you'd use to return the offset for an address in the database would be `database.offset()` which is significantly easier to remember.